# Astyle C++ indentation of variable init in constructor

Tags: c++, astyle

I'm looking for a Astyle option to indent C++ constructors from :

```
foo::foo(int param) : m_param(param)
  , m_x(0)
  , m_y(0)
```

To :

```
foo::foo(int param) : m_param(param)
                    , m_x(0)
                    , m_y(0)
```

I havn't found that in the documentation nor on google. Thanks.

Comment: @RakibulHasan I believe the question is clear enough

Comment: My question is, is there an option in order to indent these initializations. If yes, what is it.

Comment: In Astyle, Artistic Style, auto indenter, I'm using the ST3 plugin but it's the same option everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option in the current release of AStyle. It handles multi-line initializer lists as continuation lines, with no special handling applied.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, do you know any way to do it then ? Or do I have to forget it ?

Comment: @MoKaT: Your best bet would probably be adding the feature to the AStyle source, then sending the patch to Jim for inclusion. ;-) Sorry, cannot help you any further on this account. I am quite happy AStyle does as much as it does already...

Comment: Yep, maybe I'll do it if I found the time, the skill and the motivation. Thanks. Answer accepted.